# How to modify PCL voxel grid implementation?

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I would like to turn a 3D point cloud into a simple 2D occupancy grid. In my current implementation I first apply the voxel grid to a point cloud and then I manually iterate through all points in the voxelized cloud to fill in my grid. Is there a way to make it so that while I am voxelizing the grid, I am generating my 2D occupancy grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably create a new class, derive from `pcl::VoxelGrid` (see [here](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/46cb8fe5589e88e36d79f9b8b8e5f4ff4fceb5de/filters/src/voxel_grid.cpp#L177)), and implement your custom `applyFilter` which would shadow the one in the base class. This would allow you to use the same utility functions and code, and introduce your new behavior.

Comment: Hi Dexter, thank you for your kind reply. Do you know of any existing example code snippets that do something similar? I am somewhat new to all of this.

Comment: The [VoxelGridCovariance](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.1/voxel__grid__covariance_8h_source.html) class seems to do something similar.

Comment: Thank you kind sir.